# Add tailwindcss to lucky framework

Tags: laravel-mix, tailwind-css, lucky-framework

I've created a new project using the lucky framework and want to add tailwindcss. I have added it using these steps:

1. yarn add tailwindcss (https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation)
2. npx tailwindcss init (https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration)
3. Added this to webpack.mix.js (https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation)

```
mix.postCss('src/css/main.css', 'public/css', [
  require('tailwindcss'),
])
```

4. Added the following to `src/css/main.css`:

```
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
```

When I run `lucky dev` the assets are compiled but text isn't changed like in this basic example:

```
li class: "p-3 text-orange-800" do
  text "Modify this page: src/pages/me/show_page.cr"
end
```

I seem to miss some steps to make it work in this framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your `webpack.mix.js` content is quite right.

You can see how I set up Tailwind CSS in a Lucky Application in [this RailsByte](https://railsbytes.com/public/templates/VeKsGg), but basically:

Add `const tailwindcss = require("tailwindcss");` somewhere at the top of `webpack.mix.js`.

Add this to your `.options()` hash in `webpack.mix.js`, assuming your Tailwind config is in the root directory of your project:

```js
processCssUrls: false,
postCss: [ tailwindcss("./tailwind.config.js") ],
```

These are all pretty much from the **Laravel Mix** setup in the Tailwind Guides themselves, here: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation#build-tool-examples

Comment: Thank you, using your RailsByte takes all the hard work out of it. Works like a charm. :-)